# Is this edit allowed/can I appeal against it? Can someone rollback my edit then make the same edits as me?

Tags: discussion, best-practices

Okay so I've screenshotted here this dude https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z6FI.jpg essentially read that I had edited his post, took the best bits of my clear and objectively better improvement (but John why do you think it's better? show my edit vs the one after it to 100 different people, i guarantee you mine is easier to understand despite saying the same thing) and for some reason scrapped anything that made his post easier to understand? Can I appeal against this? Is this allowed? I strongly encourage you to read the edit history [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/posts/212396/revisions).
 He was edits 6/7 I was 5. He literally rolled back my edits so he could it himself to say what I wrote!? Is this behaviour allowed?? In case anyone can't understand why I'm kinda frustrated is I loss rep because of this with the rollback only for my changes to be implemented again but not by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one thing is clear Here Asim is orignal poster,

So he has all rights to ask question in his own way if he does not like your edit we can not do anything,

And if you think your edit is good then go ahead and edit others people post, And believe me most of the people like except you change the core of the post

Comment: Understood it's just that he did like the edits, because he implemented them himself, just not by me, but gotcha, what you're saying is that it's fine. Thank you